# Doc on how one function can beget another in clojurescript?

Tags: function, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to learn clojurescript through this cool site [clojurescriptkoans](http://www.clojurescriptkoans.com)

There's a problem, I'm a bit stumped on a sample question.

Question:

**Could anyone give me a clue like link me docs `docs` to help me answer?**

> One function can beget another.

```
(= 9 (((fn [] _____ )) 4 5))
```

REF: http://clojurescriptkoans.com/#functions/7

Comment: hint: the `fn` here is immediately invoked.  So whatever it has in its body becomes the function called with args `4 5`.

Comment: (= 9 (((fn [] #(+ %1 %2))) 4 5)) Was my answer but I feel like it isn't right

Comment: That is what I would have done as well

Comment: You win the vocabulary award for the first correct use of beget on the internet ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your anonymous function takes no arguments; when it is called (as is the case here), it has to return *something* that takes 4 and 5 as arguments, and returns 9. That *something* is simply another function called `+`:

`(= 9 (((fn [] + )) 4 5))`